# Como puedo ejecutar una ventana en tkinter y a su vez en esta ventana mostrar datos por treeview

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, sqlite, vscode

estoy comenzando en esto y tengo una duda en python con la librería Tkinter,
estoy intentando hacer un sistema de registros de clientes proveedores, con conexión a una base de datos en SQLite.
tengo una ventana de carga de datos de proveedores/clientes, y dos botones, uno es agregar proveedor y el otro ver proveedores, al darle click al botón ver proveedores quiero que muestre una ventana nueva con el treeview y los datos de los proveedores que haya cargado.
logro hacer que muestre una ventana nueva con el titulo pero el treeview me lo muestra en la ventana anterior.
adjunto mi código:

```
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *
from proveedor import *
import sqlite3 

class Proveedores:

# conexion a base de datos propiedades
db_name = 'database.db'


def __init__(self, window):

    # Inicializacion 
    self.wind = window
    self.wind.title('Proveedores')

    #Contenedor 
    frame = LabelFrame(self.wind, text = 'Registro de Proveedor')
    frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 40, pady = 30)

    # Entrada de Numero de cuenta
    Label(frame, text = 'Cuenta: ').grid(row = 1, column = 0)
    self.cuenta = Entry(frame)
    self.cuenta.focus()
    self.cuenta.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
    
    # Entrada de Nombre
    Label(frame, text = 'Razon Social: ').grid(row = 2, column = 0)
    self.razon_social = Entry(frame)
    self.razon_social.grid(row = 2, column = 1)
    
    # Nombre Fantasia
    Label(frame, text = 'Nombre Comercial: ').grid(row = 2, column = 2)
    self.nombre_comercial = Entry(frame)
    self.nombre_comercial.grid(row = 2, column = 4)

    # Entrada de Direccion
    Label(frame, text = 'Direccion: ').grid(row = 3, column = 0)
    self.direccion = Entry(frame)
    self.direccion.grid(row = 3, column = 1)

    #Direccion local
    Label(frame, text = 'Direccion Comercial: ').grid(row = 3, column = 2)
    self.direccion_comercial = Entry(frame)
    self.direccion_comercial.grid(row = 3, column = 4)

    # Entrada Codigo Postal - los siguientes 4 campos(CP-loc-prov-pais) son en la misma linea
    Label(frame, text = 'Codigo Postal: ').grid(row = 4, column = 0)
    self.cp = Entry(frame)
    self.cp.grid(row = 4, column = 1)

    #Entrada localidad
    Label(frame, text = 'Localidad: ').grid(row = 4, column = 2)
    self.localidad = Entry(frame)
    self.localidad.grid(row = 4, column = 4)

    #Entrada de Provincia
    Label(frame, text = 'Provincia: ').grid(row = 4, column = 5)
    self.provincia = Entry(frame)
    self.provincia.grid(row = 4, column = 6)

    #Entrada de Pais
    Label(frame, text = 'Pais: ').grid(row = 4, column = 7)
    self.pais = Entry(frame)
    self.pais.grid(row = 4, column = 8)

    ### terminan los items de la misma linea    

    # Entrada de Zona
    Label(frame, text = 'Zona: ').grid(row = 5, column = 0)
    self.zona = Entry(frame)
    self.zona.grid(row = 5, column = 1)

    #Entrada de Telefono
    Label(frame, text = 'Telefono: ').grid(row = 6, column = 0)
    self.telefono = Entry(frame)
    self.telefono.grid(row = 6, column = 1)

    #Entrada Vendedor
    Label(frame, text = 'Vendedor: ').grid(row = 7, column = 0)
    self.vendedor = Entry(frame)
    self.vendedor.grid(row = 7, column = 1) 

    #Entrada Grupo
    Label(frame, text = 'Grupo: ').grid(row = 8, column = 0)
    self.grupo = Entry(frame)
    self.grupo.grid(row = 8, column = 1) 

    #Entrada Condicion de Venta
    Label(frame, text = 'Cond. Vta.: ').grid(row = 8, column = 2)
    self.CondicionVenta = Entry(frame)
    self.CondicionVenta.grid(row = 8, column = 4)

    #Entrada de Lista de Precio
    Label(frame, text = 'List. Pre.: ').grid(row = 8, column = 5)
    self.ListaPrecio = Entry(frame)
    self.ListaPrecio.grid(row = 8, column = 6)

    #Entrada de Credito de cuenta
    Label(frame, text = 'Cred. Cuenta: ').grid(row = 8, column = 7)
    self.CreditoCta = Entry(frame)
    self.CreditoCta.grid(row = 8, column = 8)
    
    #Entrada de Condicion frente a IVA 
    Label(frame, text = 'Codigo IVA: ').grid(row = 9, column = 0)
    self.CodIVA = Entry(frame)
    self.CodIVA.grid(row = 9, column = 1)
    
    #Entrada Numero CUIT
    Label(frame, text = 'CUIT: ').grid(row = 9, column = 2)
    self.NumCUIT = Entry(frame)
    self.NumCUIT.grid(row = 9, column = 4)

    #Entrada de Numero de Ingresos Brutos
    Label(frame, text = 'Ing. Brutos: ').grid(row = 9, column = 5)
    self.NumIngBru = Entry(frame)
    self.NumIngBru.grid(row = 9, column = 6)

    #Entrada de Observaciones
    Label(frame, text = 'Observaciones: ').grid(row = 10, column = 0)
    self.observaciones = Entry(frame)
    self.observaciones.grid(row = 10, column = 1)

    
    # Boton Agregar Proveedor 
    ttk.Button(frame, text = 'Guardar Proveedor', command = self.add_proveedor).grid(row = 15, column = 3, columnspan = 3, sticky = W + E)
    
    
    #Boton Ver Lista de Proveedores
    ttk.Button(frame, text = 'Ver Proveedores', command = self.ver_proveedores).grid(row = 15, column = 7, columnspan = 3, sticky = W + E)

    # Mensajes de Salida 
    self.mensaje = Label(text = '', fg = 'red')
    self.mensaje.grid(row = 11, column = 0, columnspan = 2, sticky = W + E)

# Funcion a ejecutar en base de datos
def run_query(self, query, parameters = ()):
    with sqlite3.connect(self.db_name) as conn:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        result = cursor.execute(query, parameters)
        conn.commit()
    return result

# Validacion de datos
def validacion(self):
    return len(self.cuenta.get()) != 0 and len(self.razon_social.get()) != 0 and len(self.nombre_comercial.get()) != 0 and len(self.direccion.get()) != 0

def add_proveedor(self):
    if self.validacion():
        query = 'INSERT INTO Proveedores VALUES(NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)'
        parameters =  (self.cuenta.get(), self.razon_social.get(), self.nombre_comercial.get(), self.direccion.get(), self.direccion_comercial.get(), self.cp.get(), self.localidad.get(), self.provincia.get(), self.pais.get(), self.zona.get(), self.telefono.get(), self.vendedor.get(), self.grupo.get(),self.CondicionVenta.get(), self.ListaPrecio.get(),self.CreditoCta.get(), self.CodIVA.get(), self.NumCUIT.get(), self.NumIngBru.get(), self.observaciones.get())
        self.run_query(query, parameters)
        self.mensaje['text'] = 'Cuenta {} Se Agrego Correctamente'.format(self.cuenta.get())
        self.cuenta.delete(0, END)
        self.razon_social.delete(0, END)
        self.nombre_comercial.delete(0, END)
        self.direccion.delete(0, END)
        self.direccion_comercial.delete(0, END)
        self.cp.delete(0, END)
        self.localidad.delete(0, END)
        self.provincia.delete(0, END)
        self.pais.delete(0, END)
        self.zona.delete(0, END)
        self.telefono.delete(0, END)
        self.vendedor.delete(0, END)
        self.grupo.delete(0, END)
        self.CondicionVenta.delete(0, END)
        self.ListaPrecio.delete(0, END)
        self.CreditoCta.delete(0, END)
        self.CodIVA.delete(0, END)
        self.NumCUIT.delete(0, END)
        self.NumIngBru.delete(0, END)
        self.observaciones.delete(0, END)
    else:
        self.mensaje['text'] = 'Los Campos no Pueden estar Vacios'
    self.add_proveedor()


def ver_proveedores(self):
    self.Ventana = Toplevel()
    self.Ventana.title ('Lista de Proveedores') 
    self.tree = ttk.Treeview(height = 10, columns = ('#1','#2','#3'))
    self.tree.grid(row = 4, column = 5, columnspan = 4)
    self.tree.heading('#0', text = 'Nro. Cuenta', anchor = CENTER)
    self.tree.heading('#1', text = 'Nombre', anchor = CENTER)
    self.tree.heading('#2', text = 'Nombre Comercial', anchor = CENTER)
    self.tree.heading('#3', text = 'Domicilio', anchor = CENTER) 
    
    # limpiar tabla
    records = self.tree.get_children()
    for element in records:
        self.tree.delete(element)
    # buscar datos
    query = 'SELECT * FROM Proveedores ORDER BY Cuenta DESC'
    db_rows = self.run_query(query)
    # ordenar datos
    for row in db_rows:
        self.tree.insert('', 0, text = row[1], values = row[2:5])



if __name__ == '__main__':
window = Tk()
application = Proveedores(window)
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Explicación

Cuando creas el treeview no estás especificando en que ventana lo creas. Entonces, por default se crea en la ventana raiz (la que creas con Tk()).
Esto que te digo aplica a todos los widgets de Tkinter.

#### Solución

La clase treeview (como todo widget en Tkinter) acepta un primer argumento que es en que ventana/frame deseas crear el treeview.
Por lo tanto, la solución está en cambiar esta linea:

```
self.tree = ttk.Treeview(height = 10, columns = ('#1','#2','#3'))
```

Por esta:

```
self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self.Ventana, height = 10, columns = ('#1','#2','#3'))
```

Ya que self.Ventana es el toplevel que acabas de crear más arriba.

Estoy muy seguro de mi respuesta, así que no hice ninguna prueba. Si falla por favor avísame en los comentarios!

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!! ahora si me funciona perfecto!!

Comment: Es un placer c: Si la respuesta te sirvió, puedes apoyarme aceptándola nwn